# Custom post-type archive is not filtering posts based on category

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, archive

I made a custom post type with ACF. I am using Hello Elementor child theme where I made new archive template. The archive shows, all the posts as needed, but in order to filter them, I added two new menu items. The menu items are post type categories. I added a category to the menu through categories menu item. The problem is that posts are not filtering correctly when clicking on the menu item, that should show the posts with the following categories.

FYI I have looked through almost every single post that is about custom post-type and categories. Still haven't found the answer.

The code is following:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying archive pages.
 *
 * @package HelloElementor
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}
?>

<?php
$custom_query_args = (array(
   'post_type' => 'kampaania',
   'posts_per_page' => 10,
   'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'aktiivsed-kampaaniad',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category', 
        'field' => 'slug', 
        'terms' => 'loppenud-kampaaniad'
    ),
    ),
));

$custom_query_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args );

$temp_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query   = NULL;
$wp_query   = $custom_query;

?>
<main id="content" class="site-main">

    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'hello_elementor_page_title', true ) ) : ?>
        <header class="page-header">
            <?php
         
            the_archive_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
            the_archive_description( '<p class="archive-description">', '</p>' );
            ?>
        </header>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="page-content">
        <?php
        while ($custom_query->have_posts() ) {
            $custom_query->the_post();

            $post_link = get_permalink();
            ?>
            <article class="post">
                <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $post_link ), get_the_post_thumbnail( $post, 'large' ) );
                } ?>
            
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
               <?php 
                $field = get_field_object('kampaania_periood'); 
                $field2 = get_field_object('kampaania_kauplused');
                ?>
                <div class="bpost-title">
                    <?php
                    printf( '<h2 class="%s"><a href="%s">%s</a></h2>', 'entry-title', esc_url( $post_link ), wp_kses_post( get_the_title() ) );
                    ?>
                </div>
         
               <p class="kamp-period">
                    <span class="kamp-period-head"><?php echo $field['label']; ?></span> <?php echo $field['value']; ?>
               </p>

               <p class="post-excerpt">
                  <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
               </p>
         
               <p class="kamp-kaup"> 
                    <span class="kamp-period-head"><?php echo $field2['label']; ?></span> <?php echo $field2['value']; ?>
               </p>

               <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn-closer">Osale kampaanias</a>
            </div>
                
            </article>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

    <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>

    <?php
    global $wp_query;
    if ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 ) :
        ?>
        <nav class="pagination">
            <?php /* Translators: HTML arrow */ ?>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( sprintf( __( '%s Vanemad kampaaniad', 'hello-elementor-child' ), '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span>' ) ); ?></div>
            <?php /* Translators: HTML arrow */ ?>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( sprintf( __( 'Uuemad kampaaniad %s', 'hello-elementor-child' ), '<span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>' ) ); ?></div>
        </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>


</main>
```

Have I missed anything? Or are there any extra steps I can take?

Update: After longer inspection I realized, that even if I add custom taxonomy (which in this case is a regular category that I added through ACF as a taxonomy) to the custom query then no matter what it still gives me all the posts with the mentioned categories.

Comment: You are executing your own custom query there, but I can see no attempt whatsoever to actually implement any filtering by category for that query.

Comment: How would I implement that? Would adding category id's array under the custom query help? That did not help...

Comment: Should be done using `category__in`, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters

Comment: Tried adding the categories with `category__in` and  `'cat' => '6, 7,'` to the custom query, but either did not solve the problem. Might there be something else that I need to add to the query?

Comment: WordPress `category` taxonomy only works with WordPress `post` post type, but not with any other custom post type. So you can't use in a WP_Query for a custom post type a `tax_query` for `category` taxonomy.